# Renaming SSL Wildcard certificate while it is already associated with an IIS Web Site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, ssl-certificate

**I'm trying to find if renaming the wild card certificate would bring down the sites that are already using it (even if it is momentary) or cause any other undesirable effect? Any help or pointers on this?**

Some background on why I'm trying to do this:
I have a web application that is utilizing the wildcard certificate for a specified IP address (at port # 443) in the Production server (has IIS 7). Now, I want to utilize the same wild card certificate, IP address & port # for another web application on the same server. However, the host header text box is disabled when I try to edit binding.

Based on my findings so far and going thru few blogs, I can (either use appcmd utility to change the binding or) rename the SSL certificate's friendly name, which would enable the host header text box. Hence, I would be able to use the same wildcard certificate - IP address - Port # combination with different host header for my new web application. I tried this on my laptop and found that it successfully works. However, it renames the wild card for the site that was already using it. I did not observe any negative impact such as the existing site going down or the IIS reset occurring during this process. But, I'm not in favor of trying this out in the production environment, without fully understanding the impact of this change.

Answer (score 0):

**skip** updating my response.

Sorry, I originally misread your question. When using the same **wildcard** certificate with multiple web sites on the same IP:Port, you have to provide host headers in bindings for all affected web sites.

You said that websites rename your certificate -- they just rename Friendly Name property. This property doesn't affect anything, because it is just informative property.

You are worried about downtimes -- no, there are no downtimes. When you change the SSL certificate, you can interrupt existing SSL sessions, but this won't affect connections and their states. Clients just renegotiate SSL channel to use new certificate and won't notice that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I've tried this out on my laptop (which has IIS7) and it works for me. Using appcmd utility or using the steps outlined in https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/ssl-host-headers-iis-7.htm, it is possible to have the wildcard - IP address - Port # combination for more than 1 site on the same server.